# Parameterize SQL Queries with psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to safely pass in a query string and parameters to psycopg2, but am having trouble with formatting lists into the query. In the first file, I have a list of columns and values to pass through to another function that executes the query.

```
columns = ['id', 'name', 'address']
values = ['1234', 'john', '123 road']
query = """INSERT INTO table %s VALUES (%s)"""
parameters = (tuple(columns), tuple(values))

res = update(query, parameters)
```

In the second file I take the query string and parameter and execute them:

```
def update(query_string: str, query_parameters: tuple):
    with db.transaction() as txn:
        txn.execute(query_string, query_parameter)
```

But I get an error saying:

```
LINE 1: INSERT INTO table ('id', 'name', 'address')...
                           ^
Syntax Error
```

What would be the correct way to pass in the column and values list into the query string?

Comment: Columns are identifiers you can't use parameter substitution for them. In docs see [SQL composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for ways to do this.

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it didn't work please provide me the error or the issue you encountered.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex we ended up going with another solution that didn't involve using psycopg2. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reviewing these links for additional details on how to  generate SQL dynamically using psycopg:

- main page: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html
- section: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Placeholder

Based on your use case you can pass the list of columns name and values into a table with *psycopg2* this way.

```
def update(query_string: str, query_parameters: tuple):
    with db.transaction() as txn:
        txn.execute(query_string, query_parameter)


tableName = "your_table_name"
columns = ["id", "name", "address"]
values = ["1234", "john", "123 road"]


sql_insert_command = sql.SQL("""INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {}""").format(
        sql.Identifier(tableName),
        sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),
        sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder()*len(values)))


update(sql_insert_command, values)
```

Comment: There is no `insert_records_with_execute_values()` in `psycopg2` so this not the way to do it with `psycopg2`. See the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for the builtin way.

Comment: Nor have mentioned where `tableName` is coming from. If you post an answer please make it contained enough to be usable.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I updated my answer.  The *insert_records_with_execute_values()* was linked to this *psycopg2.extras.execute_values* in my DatabaseConnection code.

Comment: You still haven't dealt with the OPs need to dynamically add column names.  Save yourself a lot of trouble and look at the link I sent earlier. It addresses all this with a built  in procedure.